# apt-get: install modified package with dependencies

Tags: debian, apt

I have downloaded a Debian package `lxde`, together with all its dependencies:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends lxde --download-only
```

So now, I have all packages in my `/var/cache/apt/archives`. I have made modifications to one package `lxde_4+nmu1_all.deb` (removed `galculator` from dependencies) and now I would like to install lxde from my modified package (i.e. with the modified dependencies). `dpkg -i lxde_4+nmu1_all.deb` does not work, because of unmet dependencies.

How can I tell `apt-get` to install my modified package `/var/cache/apt/archives/lxde_4+nmu1_all.deb` ?

Comment: Create a repo of your own, give it a higher version number (and/or a higher pin) and verify with `apt-cache policy lxde` that your version is now preferred.

Comment: that would be an elegant solution. How would I create my own repo, by the way? Is it just the path to the files, i.e. `/var/cache/apt/archives` ?

Comment: No, it's somewhat more complex than that. You will need at least a `Packages` file (see `dpkg-scanpackages`) and these days probably a signing key.

Comment: Why not just go ahead and install the dependencies first? they are listed in `apt-cache show` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own repository with [reprepro](http://mirrorer.alioth.debian.org/) (tutorials [1](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/286) [2](http://wiki.debian.org/SettingUpSignedAptRepositoryWithReprepro) …).

If all you want to do is avoid installing galculator, an easier method is to make a fake `galculator` package with [equivs](http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.building-first-package.html). Then you can install lxde normally.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the package via `dpkg --force-depends`, you can install the dependencies and complete installation with `apt-get install -f`. This will only work in the case of "Depends". If a package is a "Pre-Depend", it must be installed prior to using `dpkg -i`.